# Can I perform sanity checking in the initializer list of a constructor?

Tags: c++, assert

Using the initializer lists is encouraged in general. Now let's say I have the following code (trivial example just to make the question clearer):

```
class foo
{
  public:
    foo(ptr1* a, ptr2* b) : m_a(a), m_b(b), m_val(a->val) {}

  /* code and members here */
};
```

I would like to check that `a` is not NULL before it tries to dereference it to get `val`. Is there any way I can perform a sanity check there?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Use the ternary operator](http://ideone.com/qe3pn):

```
#include <cstdio>

class Test
{
    int x;

public:

    Test(int *px)
    : x (px ? *px : -1)
    {
        printf("%d\n", x);
    }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    Test(NULL);
    return 0;
}
```

The above sample outputs `-1`.

Comment: That's a good enough compromise. I can then put the asserts in the constructor body and they will actually fire properly. (+1)

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
foo(ptr1* a, ptr2* b) : m_a(a), m_b(b), m_val(a==nullptr ? 0 : a->val) {}
```

Alternatively, if `a==nullptr` is an error in programming logic, you can use an assert() to catch it while unit-testing your debug builds.